# ImageField upload_to doesn't work with django update statements

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

**models.py**

```
class Movies_list(models.Model):    movies_thumbnail=models.ImageField(default='thumbnail.jpg',upload_to='movies_pics')

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
        img=Image.open(self.movies_thumbnail.path)
        if img.height > 100 or img.width > 100:
            output_size = (200,300)
            image_movies=img.resize(output_size,resample=Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image_movies.save(self.movies_thumbnail.path)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**views.py**

```
form=Update_Movies_form(
            data=(request.POST or None),
            files=(request.FILES or None),
            # instance=obj
        )
    form.fields["movies_thumbnail"].initial = obj.movies_thumbnail
    movies_detail=Movies_list.objects.filter(movies_id=movies_id)
    print(movies_detail)
    url=url_filter(request,movies_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        if request.user.is_staff:
            obj_movies_update=Movies_list.objects.filter(movies_id=movies_id).update(
                movies_thumbnail=request.FILES["movies_thumbnail"],
```

**forms.py**

```
class Create_Movies_form(forms.Form):
    movies_thumbnail=forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'thumbnail'}))
```

on update form submition it save movies_thumbnail in media folder not in media/movies_pics so i try to forcefully save it in movies_pics by replacing

> movies_thumbnail=request.FILES["movies_thumbnail"],

to

> movies_thumbnail="movies_pics/"+str(request.FILES["movies_thumbnail"]),

It save image in movies_pic and work just fine but didn't crop image as specified in models.py

> ```
> def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
>     super().save(*args,**kwargs)
>     img=Image.open(self.movies_thumbnail.path)
>     if img.height > 100 or img.width > 100:
>         output_size = (200,300)
>         image_movies=img.resize(output_size,resample=Image.ANTIALIAS)
>         image_movies.save(self.movies_thumbnail.path)
> ```

Comment: update doesn't execute save method, thats why you are not getting any cropped images.

Comment: so, what should i do to crop image

Comment: I exactly dont know your scenario, but if you want to call save for every item in queryset, just iterate through queryset and call save. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

Comment: I understand updating object didn't call save method present in models.But i don't know where i have to use `for item in my_queryset:
    item.save()`and what to replace replace with my_queryset.

Comment: `qs = Movies_list.objects.filter(movies_id=movies_id)` will be your queryset, loop over the qs like `for i in qs: i.movies_thumbnail=request.FILES["movies_thumbnail"] i.save()`. there can be more effiecient way to achieve this.